# Hiding Sections in Accordion menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created this list, which contains some information with a accordion menu.

[View The List](http://miladabedini.com/temp/stackoverflow/index.html)

The problem I have (and I'm a little confused about it), is that, when one of the menus is clicked, for example the animal menu, it's information is displayed.

After that, when the user clicks on the colors menu, the animal menu still opens, but I want, when each of the menus clicked, the previous menu closes and only the new menu stays open.
Thank you very much for guiding me in solving this problem.

```js
'use strict';


    // search & highlight

    ;( function( $, window, document, undefined )
    {
        var $container = $( '.faq' );
        if( !$container.length ) return true;

        var $input          = $container.find( 'input' ),
            $notfound       = $container.find( '.faq__notfound' ),
            $items          = $container.find( '> ul > li' ),
            $item           = $(),
            itemsIndexed    = [];

        $items.each( function()
        {
            itemsIndexed.push( $( this ).text().replace( /\s{2,}/g, ' ' ).toLowerCase() );
        });

        $input.on( 'keyup', function( e )
        {
            if( e.keyCode == 13 ) // enter
            {
                $input.trigger( 'blur' );
                return true;
            }

            $items.each( function()
            {
                $item = $( this );
                $item.html( $item.html().replace( /<span class="highlight">([^<]+)<\/span>/gi, '$1' ) );
            });

            var searchVal = $.trim( $input.val() ).toLowerCase();
            if( searchVal.length )
            {
                for( var i in itemsIndexed )
                {
                    $item = $items.eq( i );
                    if( itemsIndexed[ i ].indexOf( searchVal ) != -1 )
                        $item.removeClass( 'is-hidden' ).html( $item.html().replace( new RegExp( searchVal+'(?!([^<]+)?>)', 'gi' ), '<span class="highlight">$&</span>' ) );
                    else
                        $item.addClass( 'is-hidden' );
                }
            }
            else $items.removeClass( 'is-hidden' );

            $notfound.toggleClass( 'is-visible', $items.not( '.is-hidden' ).length == 0 );
        });
    })( jQuery, window, document );


    // toggling items on title press

    ;( function( $, window, document, undefined )
    {
        $( document ).on( 'click', '.faq h2 a', function( e )
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            $( this ).parents( 'li' ).toggleClass( 'is-active' );
        });
    })( jQuery, window, document );


    // auto-show item content when show results reduces to single

    ;( function( $, window, document, undefined )
    {
        var $container = $( '.faq' );
        if( !$container.length ) return true;

        var $input      = $container.find( 'input' ),
            $items      = $container.find( '> ul > li' ),
            $item       = $();

        $input.on( 'keyup', function()
        {
            $item = $items.not( '.is-hidden' );
            if( $item.length == 1 )
                $item.addClass( 'js--autoshown is-active' );
            else
                $items.filter( '.js--autoshown' ).removeClass( 'js--autoshown is-active' );
        });
    })( jQuery, window, document );
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  color: #34434b;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 5rem 1.25rem;
  direction: rtl;
  text-align: right;
  /* 80 20 */
}

a {
  color: #468FB3;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 640px;
  /* 960 */
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.container h1 {
  font-size: 42px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #5594b3;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.container h1 a:hover, .container h1 a:focus {
  color: #a664b7;
}
.container p {
  line-height: 1.6;
}

.faq input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(52, 67, 75, 0.2);
  display: block;
  padding: 0 20px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  -webkit-transition: box-shadow .1s linear;
  transition: box-shadow .1s linear;
}
.faq input::-webkit-input-placeholder, .faq input::-moz-placeholder, .faq input:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #a1bdcb !important;
}
.faq input:focus {
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px rgba(52, 67, 75, 0.4);
}
.faq .highlight {
  background-color: #f00d77;
}
.faq > ul > li:not(:first-child) {
  border-top: 1px solid #dcebed;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
.faq > ul > li.is-hidden {
  display: none;
}
.faq > ul > li h2 {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.faq > ul > li h2:hover, .faq > ul > li h2:focus {
  color: #a664b7;
}
.faq > ul > li.is-active h2, .faq > ul > li:target h2 {
  color: #a664b7;
}
.faq > ul > li > div {
  display: none;
}
.faq > ul > li.is-active > div, .faq > ul > li:target > div {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.faq__notfound {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-style: italic;
  display: none;
}
.faq__notfound.is-visible {
  display: block;
}

.container footer {
  color: #a1bdcb;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
.container footer a:hover, .container footer a:focus {
  color: #5594b3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<div class="container" role="main">

    <h1>LIST</h1>

    <div class="faq">
        <input type="search" value="" placeholder="Type some keywords" />
        <ul>
            <li id="faq-1">
                <h2><a href="#faq-1">Animals</a></h2>
                <div>
                    <p>
                        cat <br>
                        dog <br>
                        lion <br>
                        tiger <br>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li id="faq-2">
                <h2><a href="#faq-2">Names</a></h2>
                <div>
                    <p>
                        jim <br>
                        jack <br>
                        mary <br>
                        tom <br>
                    </p>
                
                </div>
            </li>
            <li id="faq-3">
                <h2><a href="#faq-3">colors</a></h2>
                <div>
                    <p>
                        blue <br>
                        red <br>
                    </p>
                
                </div>
            </li>
            
        </ul>
        <div class="faq__notfound"><p>No matches were found&hellip; Try &ldquo;giza&rdquo;.</p></div>
    </div>

    <footer><p></p></footer>
</div>
<!-- partial -->
<script src='./jquery.min.js'></script><script  src="./script.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow - questions should include a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in the post itself, not hosted elsewhere, so that the thread remains useful to people who may find it in the future. You need to provide a snippet that includes all relevant HTML, CSS, and especially in this case Javascript.

Comment: You can control the behavior with two CSS classes, at the first, all accordion should have "hide" class after a click on an item add the "show" class to the correct accordion, then after clicking on another one, all the accordions should have "hide" class except the active one, u can make the "show" class properties important to overwrite the "hide" class styles.

Comment: Use a toggle  behaviour using Css like transverse through list and the item you click should have show class and other have hide. so in that manner you can achieve toggling behaviour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use this function code**

```
;( function( $, window, document, undefined )
{   
    $( document ).on( 'click', '.faq h2 a', function( e )
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        var refId = $(this).parents('li').attr('id'); 
          
        $('li').each(function(){
          if(refId != $(this).attr('id')){

          $( this ).removeClass('is-active');   
          }
        });
        $( this ).parents( 'li' ).toggleClass( 'is-active' );
    });
})( jQuery, window, document );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, less code

```
$('.faq h2 a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parents('li').toggleClass('is-active').siblings().removeClass('is-active');
});
```

And also you will have to remove unwanted style from your css code like `:target`

```
.faq > ul > li.is-active h2, 
.faq > ul > li:target h2 {
  color: #a664b7;
}

.faq > ul > li.is-active > div, 
.faq > ul > li:target > div {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

to

```
.faq > ul > li.is-active h2 {
  color: #a664b7;
}

.faq > ul > li.is-active > div {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Working code : https://codepen.io/vinodmurukesan/pen/zYrMqyJ

Answer (score 0):

Please replace this function in **script.js starting from line 57** and you will see magical results..

```
;( function( $, window, document, undefined )
    {
        $( document ).on( 'click', '.faq h2 a', function( e )
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('li').each(function(){

              $( this ).removeClass('is-active');   
            });
            $( this ).parents( 'li' ).toggleClass( 'is-active' );
        });
    })( jQuery, window, document );
```

Comment: I am really grateful

Comment: @MAtiqueKhan Thank you again for your response.
I'm sorry, in this solution you said, if the user clicks on the same option again, it will not close , can this problem be solved?

Comment: I have added a better code, please copy that, it will solve the problem you mentioned here..